# Add a comma to a whole number in a specific position

Tags: python

I have a school work to do which requires us to write the pi digits using a certain formula the teachers gave us, my only issue that I can't find a way to add the comma after the 3, I've tried using format. but wasn't able to get the result I wanted

```
num = 1        
den1 = 2
den2 = 3
k=1
p = 15   # precision
ApproximationPi=0   

index=-p
enc=''

while ApproximationPi > 0 or index <= 0:
    print("ApproximationPi =", ApproximationPi,"k =", k, "index =", index)

    if index == 0:
        enc =str(+ApproximationPi)
        break
    
    enc = str(ApproximationPi % 10)+enc
    
    x=(10**p*num)//den1**k #first fraction in the parenthese
    y=(10**p*num)//den2**k #second fraction in the parenthese
    z=(10**p*4//k)  #fraction that is multiplied to the parenthese
    ApproximationPi += z*(x+y) #result
    k += 2
    
    a=(10**p*num)//den1**k #first fraction in the parenthese
    b=(10**p*num)//den2**k #second fraction in the parenthese
    c=(10**p*4//k)  #fraction that is multiplied to the parenthese
    ApproximationPi += -c*(a+b)
    k += 2
    index += 1
print("The value of pi at",p,"of precision is :",enc)
```

This is what is in the parenthese [formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yj2Rs.png)
This is what we required to do [requirement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KKatY.png)
And we're also required to have the most precision which is why i put my fractions as whole numbers

When the print comes out i get these

```
ApproximationPi = 0 k = 1 index = -15
ApproximationPi = 3117283950617282720679012345679 k = 5 index = -14
ApproximationPi = 3140850561761054267080332647462 k = 9 index = -13
ApproximationPi = 3141561587877589781655528849515 k = 13 index = -12
ApproximationPi = 3141591184360905432873027195429 k = 17 index = -11
ApproximationPi = 3141592579606350064446990772740 k = 21 index = -10
ApproximationPi = 3141592649716787165896142693710 k = 25 index = -9
ApproximationPi = 3141592653381538448859106760482 k = 29 index = -8
ApproximationPi = 3141592653578371512262887644412 k = 33 index = -7
ApproximationPi = 3141592653589156364210939576085 k = 37 index = -6
ApproximationPi = 3141592653589756389158964524349 k = 41 index = -5
ApproximationPi = 3141592653589790170213984376884 k = 45 index = -4
ApproximationPi = 3141592653589792063358192414687 k = 49 index = -3
ApproximationPi = 3141592653589792144990845475911 k = 53 index = -2
ApproximationPi = 3141592653589792144990845475911 k = 57 index = -1
ApproximationPi = 3141592653589792144990845475911 k = 61 index = 0
The value of pi at 15 of precision is : 3141592653589792144990845475911
```

I want the result to be : "The value of pi at 15 of precision is : 3.141592653589792144990845475911"

But can't manage to find a way to add the point

Comment: That's a period or decimal point, not a comma. Comma is `,`

Comment: @Barmar the comma is used as a decimal point (and the period as a thousands separator) in many cultures worldwide.

Comment: "But can't manage to find a way to add the point" Please try to think about the problem logically. What part of the `enc` string should appear before the point? Can you think of a way to get that part and display it? Can you display the point? Can you get the rest, and display it after the point? If you do all of those things, does it solve the problem? Where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I know that. And if the desired output had been `3,14...` I would have understood.

Comment: You can use math for this. You need to divide the number with a number described as "A one (1) followed by x number of zeros where x is one less than the length of the number itself). So: `enc / 10 ** (len(str(enc)) - 1)`

Answer (score 1):

Use indexing and slicing to extract the first digit and the remaining digits, and print with a `.` between them.

```
print(f"The value of pi at {p} of precision is : {enc[0]}.{enc[1:]}")
```